# Let others review your app / website / software product

Tags: feature-request

I'd really love a possibility on the web where I could get feedback on my work (I do Android apps), preferably from other programmers or people engaged in UI / UX.

I don't know how the situation is for software other than apps, but I haven't found anything like that for apps on the web except for offers that a. cost money and b. use 'normal users' as their test group.

I work at a company that employs other mobile developers, usability experts, testers etc., still I would appreciate people from other cultural or technological backgrounds to have a look at my product, share their opinion. 
But foremost this would be greatly beneficial to people who work on a project on their own and rarely get any feedback until it hits the market.

I think this would be something worth thinking about within the stackexchange universum.

What do you guys think about that?

Comment: If you want to propose a new site, check out [a51].  But in general, there isn't a site in the current SE family that would accept this type of question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Area 51.

Answer (score 6):

Even though maybe not exactly what you want, the closest thing that is already existing is [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Code Review can, among other things, help you with:

- Reviewing **working** code
- Reducing code duplication
- Improving your usage of design patterns
- Highlight potential bugs that you are not already aware of (Code Review is for improving working code, not fixing code)

If your project is open-sourced, then Code Review can be a very useful resource for you. Be aware though that our main focus is **Code** Review.